# MySQL | Условие в теле запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, обращаюсь к базе с запросом
Таблица получена запросом
**products_categories ty LEFT JOIN products tyy on ty.product_id = tyy.product_id**
[image: products INNER JOIN]

Но мне необходимо получить все товары в которых **status = A** и (Если **traking = B** то **amoung > 0**). 
*А если traking не равно B то условие amoung > 0 не должно срабатывать*

Думал сделать это с помощью CASE или IF но не совсем понял как они работают.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли такое реализовать и как?

Comment: ```WHERE status = 'A' AND (tracking != 'B' OR amount = 1)```. Предполагается, что ни одно из трёх полей не может быть NULL.

Comment: @Akina - оформите как ответ? разве что, "amount >0"...

Comment: @S.H. Ну это же вопрос из разряда "переведите мне на английский" - какая с него польза?